# rs-convert doesnt generate .ply files from a rosbag file

Tags: python, intel, ros, realsense

I am fairly new to intel's librealsense. Having recorded a rosbag file using realsense-viewer. I am trying to generate .ply file of individual frames from this rosbag. I tried using rs-convert but it didn't generate anything other than   a .log file.

```
rs-convert -i /path/to/source/name.bag -l /path/to/destination/file_prefix
```

This is the log file content.

> 02/12 21:21:29,470 WARNING [140658138625792] (playback_device.cpp:198) Playback device does not provide a matcher

Comment: For me it writes the same warning to the logs, but it still works fine. After all it's only a warning. I used the command as follows:
`rs-convert -i stream.bag -l pointclouds/`

Answer (score 0):

the realsense viewer comes with 2 different possibilities: you can swap from the 2d frame to the 3d one by clicking in the top-right area of the software. When you are in the 3d mode, you can simply save the the data as .ply by clicking on the "save" icon in the top-right area.

Comment: I guess I didn't describe the question well, I was trying to convert individual depth video frame (which is saved as a .bag file in real-sense) to .ply files. When i tried the save button it only saved a single frame. Thank you so much for the help though.